# How to access all the incoming emails for all different accounts on a mail server?

Tags: php, email, hmail-server

I am doing a small project for my college, in which I have to scan incoming emails for certain keywords. If they are clear, then only allow them to be read by user from inbox.

I am developing this in PHP using CodeIgnitor, and I am using hmailserver for mail server.

I was going to use this PHP code to access the mailbox, and fetch the mails:

```
$mb = imap_open("{host:port/imap}","username", "password" );
```

Also, something like in [this](https://garrettstjohn.com/article/reading-emails-with-php/) article.

The issue is, there will be multiple user accounts on mail server. I cannot provide username and password for every account in PHP code. How can I check the incoming email content, before the user receives it, without giving usernames and passwords of each and every account on mail server?

Comment: It looks like that is nothing you do with PHP. You'd rather use whitelists/blacklists of HMAIL Server.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal can you elaborate about whitelist/blacklist functionality please?

Comment: read this [documentation](https://www.hmailserver.com/docs)

Comment: Do you know about email piping ?

Comment: Do you want to implement a Mail Gatekeeper "for all Users" or you just want to scan
any IMAP Mailbox independently? In general, all Emails go to hMailServers \DATA\*.* folder